# Dispersion of $E$ and $p$

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum, dispersion

Is the dispersion of $E = c$. dispersion of $p$? Following that:

$\begin{aligned}E^{2}=c^{2}p^{2}+m_{0}^{2}c^{4}\\ \Delta E^{2}=\Delta c^{2}p^{2}\\ 2\Delta E=2\Delta c^{2}p\\ \Delta E=c^{2}\Delta p.\end{aligned}$

Can the relation depend of the units of c? Or one can put $c=1$?

Comment: $\Delta E^2 = 2E\,  \Delta E$ not $2 \Delta E$. Similarly $\Delta p^2$.

Answer (score 1):

No, $∆E^2$ is not $2\Delta E$: $$E^2 = p^2c^2 + (mc^2)^2$$
$$\delta(E^2)  = \delta(p^2c^2) + \delta [(mc^2)^2]$$
$$ 2E.\delta(E) = c^2(2p.\delta(p)) + 0$$
$$\delta(E) = \frac{pc^2}{E} \delta(p)$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: If p is great can we use E=p.c and get DE=cDp approximately. E.g for high velocity electrons.. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: If $pc >> mc^2$, then $ \gamma u >> c $ which would mean $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}} >> \frac{1}{\beta}$$ which would imply that the approximation works only if $ \beta >> \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. As $\beta$ can only have a maximum value of $1$, this condition cannot be satisfied for electrons. It'll work for massless particles however.

Comment: But if p is small (even not very much small but normal) one can use E=mc.c? Then DEapp. = u. Dp? Right?

Comment: Yes, that's true, because the rest energy is much larger than the kinetic energy. That does not change what I said however.

Comment: Yes surely. But this seems as a useful relation?

Comment: If $E \approx mc^2$, then $\delta E \approx 0$

Comment: Whether or not it is useful is up to you.

Comment: I imagined one can multiply by dx , use Heisenberg  and get dE.dt>h

Comment: In fact multiply by dt and then use dx=u.dt

Comment: Are you trying to derive that relation with the approximation? Because that relation is supposed to work in every case, irrespective of how large the momentum is